# Using custom control from external jar library to be loaded in FXML view

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I have a complex application architecture with a common library set as an external jar and used by both my main application (also a jar) and several packages modules (jars too...) loaded on demand by the main application.
I cannot manage to have an FXML controller from a module use a custom control from the common library.

My context is all JavaFX 8.
Everything works just fine launching the main application from the Eclipse IDE.
But when I launch my packages main application from the command line, I get some:
javafx.fxml.LoadException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set net.demo.control.MyControl field net.demo.module.modtest.gui.FormView.testcontrol to net.demo.control.MyControl

I tried forcing the classloader of the FXMLLoader to some custom URLClassLoader based on path for including module, but I am not so convinced it could help solve my problem.

Here is my sample demo FXML view loaded by th FXML Loader which fails:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import net.demo.control.MyControl?>

<fx:root fx:id="root" type="Pane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <VBox>
            <MyControl fx:id="myControl" />
        </VBox>
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

I expect the FXMLLoader to be able to import a class for a control from an external jar library.
The external jar library is recognized from modules moaded in the main app as I could manage to load resource files from the common lib into the modules.

Comment: It seems to think the type declared in the FXML file is different from the type declared in the controller class; however, the fully qualified names are equal. Are you using custom `ClassLoader`s? If you are, how are you creating them? Which classes are visible to which loaders?

Comment: @Slaw I use standard FXML loading...

Comment: @Slaw 
`FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getFXML())`

with 

` protected URL getFXML() {

  return getClass().getResource("/gui/Form.fxml");
 }
`

Comment: @Slaw And ` loader.getClassLoader().getURLs()` shows common lib in the list...

Comment: I think a [mcve] is necessary. When I read "_complex application architecture..._" I was imagining some sort of plugin system with custom/user-made `ClassLoader`s to load JARs on demand. I was thinking maybe the problem could be related to different `ClassLoader`s loading the "same" `Class`, considering the error message (_Note: `ClassLoader` != `FXMLLoader`_).

Comment: Thank you for your help. i will try to set up a mcve.

Comment: But doesn't the FXMLLoader use some classLoader underneath to access resources and classes ?

Comment: Yes, and it will use the the calling `Thread`'s context class loader unless one is explicitly set either on the instance or statically (i.e. `FXMLLoader.setDefaultClassLoader`).